# Ionic 2 & wordpress (how to "a minute ago, hours ago, etc)

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have some problem to assign Date.now() //my assumption for get current time.
i've make a post in my wordpress. then in ionic i want to set the post time like "a hours ago, days ago, etc"
here's my code

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';    

@Pipe({
  name: 'timesago'
})
@Injectable()
export class Timesago {

  transform(value, args) {

    let now = Date.now();
    let timepost = (now - value) / 1000;

    if (timepost < 60) {
      return `${Math.floor(timepost)}second ago`;
    } else if (timepost < 3600) {
      return `${Math.floor(timepost / 60)}minute ago`;
    } else if (timepost < 86400) {
      return `${Math.floor(timepost / 3600)}hour ago`;
    } else {
      return `${Math.floor(timepost / 86400)}day ago`;
    }
  }
}
```

output be : NaNd day ago

"value" is date wordpress post, i know it when i using console.log(value).
i've tried using console.log(now); //output be "1745432145", i don't know it's data of current time or not. but, i think it's not adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solve with plugin moment.js. that plugin so adorable. my friends tell me to using that plugin.

here's my code to make "a days ago, etc" in post

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

/*
  Generated class for the Timesago pipe.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html for more info on
  Angular 2 Pipes.
*/
@Pipe({
  name: 'timesago'
})
@Injectable()
export class Timesago {
  now:any;

  /*
    Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
   */
  transform(value, args) {
    this.now = moment(value).fromNow();
    return this.now;
  }
}
```

very simple, the power of plugin.